# Difference between two quadratic variations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, quadratic-variation

Let $t<u$ and $\pi = \{0=t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_{m(\pi)}=t\}$ of $[0,t]$, where mesh$(\pi)=\max_i(t_{i+1}-t_i)$.

Given that $[X,Y]_u$ and $[X,Y]_t$ satisfy the limit
\begin{align}
[X,Y]_t = \lim_{\text{mesh}(\pi) \to 0} \sum_i (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_{i}})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_{i}}) \qquad \text{in probability.}
\end{align}

To show that,
\begin{align}
(*) [X,Y]_u - [X,Y]_t = \lim_{\text{mesh}(\pi) \to 0} \sum_i (X_{s_{i+1}}-X_{s_{i}})(Y_{s_{i+1}}-Y_{s_{i}}) \qquad \text{in probability,}
\end{align}
taken over partitions $\{s_i\}$ of $[t,u]$ as the mesh tends to $0$.

I started with,
\begin{align}
&[X,Y]_u - [X,Y]_t \\
&= \lim_{\text{mesh}(\pi) \to 0} \sum_i (X_{u_{i+1}}-X_{u_{i}})(Y_{u_{i+1}}-Y_{u_{i}}) - (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_{i}})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_{i}}).  
\end{align}

Now, for me it is unclear how to choose the partition of $[t,u]$ such that equality $(*)$ holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $t \leq u$ and $\epsilon>0$. By the very definition of $[X,Y]_t$ and $[X,Y]_u$, we can choose $\delta>0$ such that

$$\left| [X,Y]_t - \sum_{t_i \in \Pi} (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}) \right| \leq \epsilon \tag{1} $$

and

$$\left| [X,Y]_u - \sum_{t_i \in \Pi'} (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}) \right| \leq \epsilon \tag{2}$$

for any partition $\Pi$ and $\Pi'$ of $[0,t]$ and $[0,u]$, respectively, with mesh size $\leq \delta$. Now let $\tilde{\Pi}$ be an arbitrary partition of $[t,u]$ with mesh size $\leq \delta$. Define a partition of $[0,t]$ by

$$\Pi' := \left\{ 0 = t_0 \leq t_1 := \frac{t}{n} \leq t_2 := 2 \frac{t}{n} \leq \ldots \leq t_n := t \right\}$$

where $n$ is chosen sufficiently large such that $\text{mesh}(\Pi') \leq \delta$. Obviously, $\Pi := \Pi' \cup \tilde{\Pi}$ is a partition of $[0,u]$ with mesh size $\leq \delta$. Since

$$\left| [X,Y]_u-[X,Y]_t - \sum_{t_i \in \tilde{\Pi}} (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}) \right| = \left| [X,Y]_u-[X,Y]_t - \left( \sum_{t_i \in \Pi} - \sum_{t_i \in \Pi'} (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}) \right) \right|$$

it follows from $(1)$, $(2)$ and the triangle inequality that

$$\left| [X,Y]_u-[X,Y]_t - \sum_{t_i \in \tilde{\Pi}} (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}) \right| \leq 2 \epsilon.$$

Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, this finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks saz! A question about your solution: why can you decompose the sum $\sum_{t_i \in \bar{\Pi}} (X_{t_{i+1}} - X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}} - Y_{t_i})$ into the two different sums over $\Pi '$ and $\tilde{\Pi}$ again? Or, what do you mean by $\sum_{t_i \in \Pi'} + \sum_{t_i \in \tilde{\Pi}} (X_{t_{i+1}} - X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}} - Y_{t_i})$?

Comment: @iJup I wrote it this way to briefen the notation; more rigorously it should read $$\sum_{t_i \in \Pi'} (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}) + \sum_{t_i \in \tilde{\Pi}} (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i})(Y_{t_{i+1}}-Y_{t_i}).$$ That we can split up the sum in this way follows simply from the fact that we have defined $\Pi$ as the union of the two partitions $\Pi'$ (of $[0,t]$) and $\tilde{\Pi}$ (of $[t,u]$).

Comment: Okay, I thought so! In this way, shouldn't it be $t_{i} \in \Pi$ in the line above the 'double' summation line instead of $t_{i} \in \tilde\Pi$?

Comment: @iJup Yeah, thanks; I got confused with my own notation. Should be fine now.